# Linq query to select any in list against a list

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core code-first, and I want to find any record with a similar list of a foreign entities to the entity I already have.

```
public class ClownModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }
}
public class CarModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var MyClown = new ClownModel() { /*add properties*/ } 
//or maybe an existing record selected from database, just some ClownModel instance
```

Basically, "Select all the ClownModels where they have any Cars.Id that are in my MyClown.Cars"

Comment: What does a `ClownModel` represent? I know this is for demonstration purposes, but I'm having a hard time grokking your domain-model here...

Comment: @Dai it's a matchmaking system, finding any of X that match with any in another user's list of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ClownModel` has unique `CarModel` Id's, you can use the following query:

Matches All Ids

```cs
var ids = MyClown.Cars.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();

var query = 
    from cm in ctx.ClownModel
    where cm.Cars.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)).Count() == ids.Count
    select cm;
```

Matches Any Ids

```cs
var ids = MyClown.Cars.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();

var query = 
    from cm in ctx.ClownModel
    where cm.Cars.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)).Any()
    select cm;
```

Comment: I think this is close... I'm looking for "any match", I think `== ids.Count` will return exact matches? So maybe `.Count() > 0` is what I'm looking for, will test it out...

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the "other" syntax? I forget which is which.